# Give a proof of validity.

Tags: logic

Show that First Order Logic (FOL) sentence is valid. Give a proof of validity.

```
(∀x · ∃y · P(x) ∨ Q(y)) ⇐⇒ (∀x · P(x)) ∨ (∃y · Q(y))
```

I know this is valid and can be proved by contradiction that every model M of the LHS is a model of the RHS and vice versa but I cant write if formally.

Comment: There are a few different formal proof systems — which one are you using? Is it natural deduction?

Comment: first order logic @zaq

Comment: @art we can see that you're using FOL. it would be helpful to know which rules of inference you're permitted or wanting to use. For instance, are you using conjunction introduction, conditional proof, etc? Please list all of the ones you can use. Otherwise, you may get a proof that is unsatisfying and a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @art so... conditional proof is the only rule of inference you are using? not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you're looking for.  Note that, in logic, the term "formal proof" has a very specific meaning, so if you're looking for the standard mathematical type of proof, it'd be better to use something like "rigorous proof" in the future. Also, I'm not sure if you were specifically looking for a proof by contradiction, but it seems to be an unnecessary complication here. If you were looking for that, let me know.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model of $\forall x \exists y (P(x) \lor Q(y))$. Let $a \in \mathcal{M}$ be arbitrary. By assumption, there exists a $b \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $P(a) \lor Q(b)$. If $P(a)$ holds, then $\forall x P(x)$ holds, as $a$ was arbitrary. Otherwise, $Q(b)$ holds, so $\exists y Q(y)$ holds. That proves one direction.

For the other direction, let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model of $\forall x P(x) \lor \exists y Q(y)$. If $\forall P(x)$ holds, let $a, b \in \mathcal{M}$ be arbitrary. Then $P(a)$ holds by assumption, so $P(a) \lor Q(b))$ holds. But then $\forall x \exists y (P(x) \lor Q(y)$ holds, as $a$ was arbitrary. Otherwise, $\exists y Q(y)$ holds. Then there exists some $b \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $Q(b)$ holds. Let $a \in \mathcal{M}$ be arbitrary. As $Q(b)$ holds, so does $P(a) \lor Q(b)$. But then, as $a$ was arbitrary, $\forall x \exists y (P(x) \lor Q(y))$ holds. That proves the other direction.